# If an encrypted folder is decrypted on a USB, then the USB is unplugged, how can I protect the data?

Tags: linux, usb, encryption

I have a USB with Debian Linux installed on it. I've encrypted a folder with sensitive data...

- created a key
- tar'd a directory
- encrypted the tar file using openssl and key

If the folder is decrypted...

- decrypt the encrypted tar file using openssl and key
- untar the directory

...so I can run an executable from that decrypted folder and then in a worst case scenario **if someone just unplugs the USB, how can I protect that sensitive data?** Other scenarios that could leave the data unencrypted that I could imagine are `shutdown now` or `reboot now` commands. Someone could...

- mount the USB (and specific partition with the sensitive data) on a system they have root access to and pull the decrypted data off the drive
- plugin the USB and run Linux and access the data or send it somewhere else via rsync or some other method
- copy the entire image of the USB and flash it onto a new USB

Wondering if I can...

- prevent mounting the drive to another system
- or run a clean up script on mount
- run a cleanup script on `shutdown now` or `reboot now`

I've read and know I can...

- run a script to clean up the data on `reboot` (different than `reboot now`) or `shutdown` (different than `shutdown now`) or on startup.

I'd prefer...

- to and am only using a password keyfile and not a manually entered password (I understand the risks)
- to and am using a bash script (as opposed to a GUI) to decrypt sensitive data and run an executable
- not to encrypt a partition

**Any help/ideas on cleaning up or protecting that sensitive data when the USB is unplugged are welcome!**